# calloc() call result is not captured - Objective C-IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, veracode

I uploaded my IOS application in Veracode for vulnerability scanning and got two vulnerabilities.

***First One***

**"The result of this call to calloc() is not captured, so it cannot be checked for success. This can result in application instability or crashing if memory is not available."**

This is the calloc() line:

```
currentElementBuffer->elements = (TBLElement*)calloc(1,sizeof(TBLElement)*100);
```

***Second***

**"Standard random number generators do not provide a sufficient amount of entropy when used for security purposes. Attackers can brute force the output of pseudorandom number generators such as rand()."**

I couldn't figure it out, as Iam new to this.
Anyone have any Idea how to fix this, or what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You do not check the result of `calloc` call to see if it did succeed. It might fail if memory is constrained.

2) `rand()` function is not sufficiently secure, replace it with more appropriate one for your use case (probably `arc4random()` )

Comment: Can you explain how can I call calloc() ? because someone else created the code and I have to edit it... I don't understand it..
Do you mean before I assign it to a variable, I should call it and check whether the result is not Null ?

Comment: Yes, thats right. You have to check if the result is not NULL